# Portrait by default, How can some special screens auto rotated or force some screens to landscape?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, orientation

In my app, the orientation is portrait by default, but in some special screens I want the viewcontroller to be auto rotated or to force the orientation to landscape.

in **AppDelegate.swift** :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

// portrait by default
var interfaceOrientations:UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait {
    didSet{
        // force to portrait
        if interfaceOrientations == .portrait {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue,
                                      forKey: "orientation")
        }
            // force to landscape
        else if !interfaceOrientations.contains(.portrait){
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue,
                                      forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return interfaceOrientations
}
```

in only portrait vc:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = .portrait
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = .portrait
}
```

in auto rotated vc:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = .allButUpsideDown
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = .portrait
}
```

in only landscape vc:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = [.landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    appDelegate.interfaceOrientations = .portrait
}
```

but it still has bugs...Help me

Answer (score 0):

You should force the rotation with:

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

You also have to enable autoRotation

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool{
    return true
}
```

And of course, in your project settings you have to enable both portrait and landscapes modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom your Portrait View Controller and Landscape View Controller. LandscapeViewController like this:

```

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
 }

 override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
 }

 override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeRight
 }

 override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeRight
 }
```

```

Some points need to notice: UIViewController can't decide to rotate automatically, you can use UINavigationController to fetch the value of rotation property:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return (self.topViewController?.shouldAutorotate)!
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return (self.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations)!
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return (self.topViewController?.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)!
}
```